# How to close a specific MDI Child form from another MDI Child form

Tags: c#, .net

I'm opening a MDI child form from another mdi child and it's working, but now I have to close it by the same way and nothing happens.

Here is an example of code i'm using:

```
private void checkbox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Form1 newForm1 = new Form1();
    newForm1.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;

    if (checkbox1_CheckedChanged.Checked == true)
    {
        newForm1.Show(); //this is working
    }
    else
    {
        newForm1.Dispose(); //this is not working. I have tryed .Close(), .Hide()... unsucessfully.
    }
}
```

Explaining: i have this checkbox1 in a mdi child and when it's checked another mdi child (newForm1) will open, and when it's unchecked this mdi child (newForm1) will close, hide or something like this.

Any suggestions?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "find" the form in the form collection in order to dispose of it:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (checkBox1.Checked) {
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    form1.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
    form1.Show();
  } else {
    Form found = this.MdiParent.MdiChildren.Where(x => 
                 x.GetType() == typeof(Form1)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (found != null) {
      found.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

This assumes there is only one Form1 form in the collection.

---

The other way to do this is to declare the form variable outside of the check changed method scope:

```
Form1 form1;

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (checkBox1.Checked) {
    if (form1 == null || form1.IsDisposed) {
      form1 = new Form1();
      form1.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
      form1.Show();
    }
  } else {
    if (form1 != null) {
      form1.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: LarsTech, I tryed the second way and it worked! edit: and I will use the first one to study the form colletions that you mentioned. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a public method in Form1 like:

```
Public void closeForm()
{
  Close();
 }
```

And in the code you have shown instead of

```
 newForm1.Dispose()
```

It would be:

```
 newForm1.closeForm();
```

Comment: hi Thirdy, it's weird, i think your solution should work but nothing happens like all the other methods I tryed. but thanks anyway.

Comment: Honestly i did not try this one just wrote it straight from memory and experience but as you've said @Rafael it should work. Ill open my laptop bcoz i am using a tablet right now and try it there.

Comment: Exact same problem as the OP's code.  This closes a form that was never shown.

Comment: @HansPassant I understand what you are saying but as per "showing" per se is concerned it showed. What did the damage on my code is that using his own code where Form1 is instantiated outside the if condition thus creating a new Form1 every time the checkbox is clicked and as you've said it is [technically] not shown.